# CoreLocation not working with MonoMac

Tags: c#, mono, core-location, monomac

Ok, so I'm trying to use CoreLocation in a mono mac app. After a few attempts at getting it to work with no luck (the `.UpdatedLocation` event is never raised), I grabbed this sample from the [MonoMac repository](https://github.com/mono/monomac/tree/master/samples/WhereIsMyMac).

The configuration/use of the CLLocationManager seems pretty straightforward:

```
locationManager = new CLLocationManager();
locationManager.UpdatedLocation += HandleLocationManagerUpdatedLocation;
locationManager.Failed += HandleLocationManagerFailed;
locationManager.StartUpdatingLocation();
```

Unfortunately, it seems the results were the same there as the location is never shown:

[image: Where Is My Mac Sample App]

So is there some sort of setting on the mac that I need to enable for this to work? `CLLocationManager.LocationServicesEnabled` is returning true when I check it at runtime.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Mountain Lion I see the same issue that Joel is seeing.  The update never occurs.  I created a sample obj-c app and that does work.  In the console log I see these errors with the MonoMac app:

```
9/16/12 8:06:34.291 AM com.apple.launchd.peruser.501[154]: (com.apple.CoreLocationAgent) Throttling respawn: Will start in 1 seconds
9/16/12 8:06:35.332 AM CoreLocationAgent[7744]: CodeSigningInforequest for pid=7739 
9/16/12 8:06:35.333 AM CoreLocationAgent[7744]: getting requirement data failed for pid=7739
```

But for the obj-c app it looks like:

```
9/16/12 8:02:18.143 AM CoreLocationAgent[7674]: locationRequest for pid=7670 message=0
9/16/12 8:02:20.196 AM CoreLocationAgent[7674]: locationRequest for pid=7670 response=1
```

I have not determined the cause.

Comment: I appreciate the effort looking into it. I wonder if I could convince you to check the setting that @Dyna mentions in his answer and see if that works for you.

Comment: I did look at the settings Dyna mentioned.  I again had the same result as Joel.  I believe it is a Mountain Lion issue... something changed.  In the objc-c sample I put together a popup occurs asking me to grant permission to the app, in the C# version no popup, just the errors in the logs.  @Joel are you on Mountain Lion?

Comment: Best change is to file a bug/issue with MonoMac then. Since it's an official example that fails, there might be a quick fix from the developers.

Answer (score 3):

Make sure you have allowed the WhereIsMyMacApp to allow accessing the location service. If you missed the pop-up which is shown the first time you run the programm, you MUST set the checkbox in "System Settings -> Security -> Privacy". If you miss to set a checkbox for the application but have the location service enabled, `CLLocationManager.LocationServicesEnabled` will be true but your app won't be able to use the service.

Here's how it looks on my machine:
[image: Location Settings]

(sorry that it's german, but you should be able to find the setting on your Mac). Just tested the MonoMac sample WhereIsMyMac on Lion with MonoMac 1.0 tarball compiled from source, works as a charm.

Comment: Ahh, indeed I did find the app on this list ... it never prompted me (or I didn't notice) and was unchecked here. Unfortunately, once I checked it and re-ran the app it still didn't. I cleaned and rebuilt the app, tried it in release mode, renamed it, rebooted the computer. All to no avail, the app still does not update the location :(

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. However, with the OS X 10.8.3 and latest MonoMac built from source (as of a 7e55bb19cf27afe44b53eacb33643397921aafb9) this is now working again.